# Failed to check against Nt Authority\System SID

Tags: c, security, winapi

I have a process which can be spawned by a service with either `NT AUTHORITY\Network Service` or `NT AUTHORITY\System`, and i need to check for it. So i have written a code like this:

```
if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &hToken)) {

        GetTokenInformation(hToken, 1, 0, 0, &dwOut);
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
            hTokenUser = (TOKEN_USER*)malloc( dwOut );
            if (!GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenUser, hTokenUser, dwOut, &dwOut))
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;

        PSID psid = NULL;
        SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY ntAuth = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
        AllocateAndInitializeSid(&ntAuth, 1, SECURITY_LOCAL_SYSTEM_RID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &psid);


        if (EqualSid(psid, hTokenUser->User.Sid)) {
            bResult = TRUE;
        }
}
```

So what i do, i get current process token, and i get a SID from it using `GetTokenInfo` then i create the `NT_AUTHORITY\System` SID, using `AllocateAndInitializeSid`, and i compare two values together, however, it never works, when the process is run under `NT_AUTHORITY\System` check is always failing. Is this the correct way to get `NT_AUTHORITY\System` SID and compare it with the process sid?

Comment: you have memory leaks and not check any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your code leaks handles and memory but it does provide the correct result on my machine. It might be different on your system so it would really help if you print out the result and GetLastError of every function call to help you debug. You should also code your function so you can tell the difference between errors and a negative (successful) result.

```
HRESULT isSystemUser()
{
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
    HANDLE hToken;
    if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    {
        TOKEN_USER *pTU = NULL;
        DWORD dwOut;
        GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenUser, 0, 0, &dwOut);
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
            pTU = (TOKEN_USER*) malloc(dwOut), hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
        if (pTU)
        {
            if (GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenUser, pTU, dwOut, &dwOut))
            {
                PSID psid = NULL;
                SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY ntAuth = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
                if (AllocateAndInitializeSid(&ntAuth, 1, SECURITY_LOCAL_SYSTEM_RID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &psid))
                {
                    hr = EqualSid(psid, pTU->User.Sid) ? S_OK : S_FALSE;
                    FreeSid(psid);
                }
                else
                    hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

            }
            else
                hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
            free(pTU);
        }
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    }
    else
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    return hr;
}

...

    printf("isSystemUser=%d\n", isSystemUser()); // 0 = true, 1 = false, < 0 = error
```

and when running it:

```
C:\windows\system32>c:\test.exe
isSystemUser=0    

C:\windows\system32>whoami
nt authority\system
```

Is it possible that you are not actually running as the real System user? What does [`ConvertSidToStringSid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376399(v=vs.85).aspx) return for your TokenUser?

Comment: this code must give correct result on all comps and windows - local system sid (*S-1-5-18*) is invariant. however for check instead `AllocateAndInitializeSid` + `EqualSid` much better use `*GetSidSubAuthorityCount(Sid) == 1 && *GetSidSubAuthority(Sid,0) == SECURITY_LOCAL_SYSTEM_RID`

Comment: + compare `GetSidIdentifierAuthority` with `SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY`

Comment: I know the SID is the same on all machines, the question is, is he really running as SYSTEM or something else.

Comment: yes, op or not run under *system* or have some error in code